# Is there a simple way to wrap text in a WPF ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have searched around for this, found some solutions related to Winforms, and some even just saying it is really difficult in WPF to accomplish, but those posts are quite old.

If I have a standard `ListBox`, which is declared as:

```
<ListBox 
    x:Name="listBox" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="240" 
    Margin="401,68,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="345" 
    SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>`
```

and programmatically:

```
System.ComponentModel.BindingList<string> listItems = new System.ComponentModel.BindingList<string>();
listBox.ItemsSource = listItems;
```

Is there a way for these strings to be wrapped within the `ListBox`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not hard at all:

```
<ListBox
    ....
    >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding}"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: The Grid is not necessary..Also, you may also want to explain to him what a "DataTemplate" is.

Comment: Ok, I've tried this and it is working. As d.moncada suggested, I didn't include the grid. I guess the key here was `Text="{Binding}"` in the TextBlock, as the entry will show up blank without that. Thanks.

Comment: ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" is also key. Without this it will not wrap.

Answer (score 0):

If you got StackPanel please get rid of them. They are bad with wrapping. Use GRID instead like @EdPlunkett suggested.

To use this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyErrors, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                          Template="{StaticResource ErrorListContainerTemplate}"
                                          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ErrorListStyle}"
                                         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                          />
```

Here is my style code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="WrappingStyle">
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow"/>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="ContentPresenter" x:Key="ErrorListStyle">
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBoxBorderErrorColor}"/>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Margin="0,5">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Path Grid.Column="0" Fill="{DynamicResource TextBoxBorderErrorColor}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Path.Data>
                                <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="2.5" RadiusY="2.5"/>
                            </Path.Data>
                        </Path>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource WrappingStyle}"/>
                            </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```